# Passing a JSON array to fulfillmentText

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have an array of JSON objects that looks like this...

```
JSONarray = 
[ { name: 'Steven' },
  { name: 'Clark' },
  { name: 'Kensington' } ]
```

With respect to dialogflow and google assistant I would need to send a webhook response that looks something like this...

```
"fulfillmentText": JSONarray}),
  "fulfillmentMessages" : [
          {
            "text":
              {"text": [JSONarray]
            }
          }
        ]}
```

The issue I have is this piece "fulfillmentText": JSONarray. 'fulfillmentText' is the part that Google Assistant reads back and ideally I want to have it read back each of the three names but if I just pass the array it fails. Is there away I can build the JSON that will let this happen?

Answer (score 2):

First, a minor semantic point. That is not a "JSON Array". It is an array of JavaScript Objects. JSON refers to the string representation of those objects (JavaScript Object Notation).

This is important because "fulfillmentText" expects a string. You can turn JavaScript objects into a string by using the `JSON.stringify()` method, so you'd do something like

```
const text = JSON.stringify( JSONarray );
```

However, this probably isn't what you want, since the Assistant would read this out as something like

> Open bracket open brace quote name quote colon quote Steven quote close bracket, ...

and so forth.

Instead, you probably should write a function that takes the array and turns it into a string. Simplistically, you could call `join()` on just the values of the names. Something like this:

```
const names = JSONarray.map( o => o.name );  // Gets just an array of the names
const namesString = names.join(', ');  // Joins them into a single string, separated by commas
const text = `The names are: ${namesString}`;
```

This is better, and what would be read out is something like

> The names are Steven, Clark, Kensington

But this isn't how people actually read (or listen to) names. We expect it to be something more like

> The names are Steven, Clark, and Kensington

This is so common that [multivocal](https://multivocal.info/) includes a template function to do this based on a list of strings. So your template would just be something like:

```
"The names are: {{Oxford names}}"
```

If you're not using multivocal, something like this would work:

```
/**
 * Similar to Array.join(), but using rules for the Oxford comma.
 * @param values The array to return joined values for
 * @param sep1 The normal separator for each element (defaults to ", ")
 * @param sep2 The separator before the final element (defaults to "and ")
 * @returns {*}
 */
function oxford( values, sep1=", ", sep2="and " ){
  if( !Array.isArray( values ) ){
    return values;
  } else if( values.length === 0 ){
    return '';
  } else if( values.length === 1 ){
    return values[0];
  } else if( values.length === 2 ){
    return values[0]+' '+sep2+values[1];
  }

  var ret = '';

  for( var co=0; co<values.length-1; co++ ){
    ret += values[co]+sep1;
  }
  ret += sep2;
  ret += values[values.length-1];

  return ret;
};

const namesString = oxford( names );
const text = `The names are: ${namesString}`;
```